# Convert jquery to javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, resize-crop

if you can, please advise me how to:

1. I need to convert this a nice script, to pure javascript without jquery.
2. Very important! The selection area Need to keep aspect ratio.

http://www.script-tutorials.com/html5-image-crop-tool/

Comment: are you serious ??? can you give me one good reasons why not jquery ??

Comment: i think that's ok for native javascript, but only needs a lot of work

Comment: "are you serious ??? can you give me one good reasons why not jquery ??" Pal, i work on project wich uses pure javascript

Comment: The easiest way (although not the quickest) is to examine the jQuery code-base of what is getting called. jQuery is nothing more than a library built on JavaScript. So look at the methods that are used in the library and utilize the JavaScript in your own library. Either way you're going to have a library in there be it jQuery or your own. 

With that being said I assume that this library is going to be non-dependent which is good.

Answer (score 1):

Well, i don't know why you need that but you need to use **HTML DOM / Mouse Events** instead of jQuery events:

[object.onmousemove](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmousemove.asp)

[object.onmouseup](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseup.asp)

[object.onmousedown](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmousedown.asp)

Also you need to use an inmediate function instead the jQuery document ready shortcut `$(function(){...})`:

```
(function(){
  // ... your code goes here
})()
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I know mouse events and document ready, I have issues with this piece of code:                            $('#panel').mousedown(function(e) { // binding mousedown event

        var canvasOffset = $(canvas).offset();

        iMouseX = Math.floor(e.pageX - canvasOffset.left);

        iMouseY = Math.floor(e.pageY - canvasOffset.top);

Comment: var canvasOffset = $(canvas).offset()